# Import css/scss file into a class

Tags: css, sass

I have a problem. I'm using vaadin inside liferay. I've successfully written a fully responsive (yeah, tables too) theme for vaadin, based on bootstrap. Now I'm importing it to liferay. Everything went fine 'till I needed to upgrade Liferay, where their new responsive theme is using same classes name as bootstrap, but with different behaviour (sad, very sad face).

The solution I've thought so far is to apply a class to the vaadin compiled css, like:

```
.daVaadinTheme {
    @import bootstrap.css;   
}
```

so the content will be compiled like:

```
.daVaadinTheme h1.insideTheFile{

}     
.daVaadinTheme h2.insideTheFile{

}
```

But, as you may figured out, is not obviously working.

Do you have any solution?

Read carefully! This is NOT a duplicate of the answer you've posted. I'm trying to import a CSS file inside a CSS/SCSS class of another file, like the example I've written above. My problem is not to simply import a CSS file inside another one...

Comment: is this .daVaadinTheme {@import bootstrap.css;} in a .scss file?

Comment: in that case the correct syntax is @import 'path-to-your-file/_bootstrap.scss'; add the underscore and the .scss extension to the bootstrap.css - i'm not sure of the output though

Answer (score 25):

Name your inner file with an underscore, and ending in scss. .Yes, even if it's plain css, i.e. `foo.css` → `_foo.scss`

Have an outer File like so:

```
#main .content {  // if that's, where you want them to rule only
    @import 'foo';
}
```

**Reasons:**

- import only works with scss
- underscore-files are glady skipped by sass (also as in `gulp.src(<some wildcards).sass()`)
- if you have no influence in your repo about the css filename whatsoever. or it's a major pain on upgrades, consider using a symbolic link under an .scss extension...

Answer (score 9):

You need move your code into `mixin`:

```
// botstrap.scss
@mixin bootstrap {
  h1.insideTheFile{
  }
  h2.insideTheFile{
  }
}
```

Then, you can import normal:

```
// test.scss
@import "bootstrap"; // No extension
@include bootstrap; // The name of "mixin"
```

or with context:

```
// test.scss
@import "bootstrap"; // No extension

.daVaadinTheme {
  @include bootstrap; // The name of "mixin"
}
```

Answer (score -5):

If you want to add certain styles to a class using sass/scss I think what you're looking for is

```
.myClass { @import bootstrap.css; }
```

Comment: Tried, but sass is not accepting it... I've tried with both, with and without apex.

Comment: Try getting the bootstrap.sass and @include that instead

Comment: it is not working. and it should not. bootstrap css will not be encapsulated, but only imported on top layer.