# Force sass-loader to modify css files

Tags: webpack, sass, css-loader, sass-loader

I'm trying to configure `sass-loader`, so it transpiles `.css` files as if they are `.scss`. However it always just outputs css files as they are.

Here's the minimal setup:

**package.json**:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.3",
    "webpack": "^4.12.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.3",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.4.0"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**:

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
module.exports = {
  entry: "./main.sass",
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.sass', '.css'],
  },
  plugins: [new MiniCssExtractPlugin()],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.sass$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          "css-loader",
          "sass-loader?indentedSyntax",
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          "css-loader",
          "sass-loader",
        ]
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

**a.fff** (let's see what happens if sass-loader faces unknown extension):

```
.black {
    background-color: black
}
```

**b.css**:

```
.red {
    background-color: red
}
```

**main.sass**:

```
body
    @import "./a.fff"
    @import "./b.css"
```

Ok. now let's run it `node ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js`, and check **dist/main.css**:

```
.red {
    background-color: red
}

body { }
  body .black {
    background-color: black; }
```

As you can see, `a.fff` was transpiled correctly, but `css` was just pasted as it is. What I want to get it is:

```
body { }
  body .black {
    background-color: black; }
  body .red {
    background-color: red; }
```

Is there any way I can force sass-loader to threat `.css` files as `.scss`?

Comment: I think the different extensions are pretty hard-coded into sass-loader: [like here](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/blob/c3482816df15efa33e7c7652fe6ce73ccc73e986/lib/importsToResolve.js#L30) Maybe you could just [rename them](https://github.com/ax-schneider/rename-loader) into .scss directly in the loader-pipeline and then feed them to sass-loader?

Comment: I wish I could, so I wouldn't waste so much time, the issue is that `css` files are located in 3rd party library, like here https://github.com/isagalaev/highlight.js/tree/master/src/styles

Comment: Yeah, but doing it in a loader it could look like `{
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          "css-loader",
          "sass-loader", 
          {loader: "rename-loader", options{filename:"[name].scss'}}
         ]
      },`  this is just guessing though, but it's a very small loader so I wonder  how hard it could be to customize.https://github.com/ax-schneider/rename-loader/blob/master/index.js

Comment: I tried that already, and put it in example above, it didn't work :( The idea about renaming is brilliant. I guess I could do like `@import 'runTimefile.scss'` in code and add something like `CopyFileWebpackPlugin('old.css', 'runTimefile.scss')` Do you have any sketches to accomplish it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, you are going to love this answer...

```
body
    @import "./a.fff"
    @import "./b"
```

Yup, leaving out the extension will resolve ./b.css AND treat it as scss syntax.
Send me your paycheck. ;)

Bonus trivia:
Your second rule `test: /\.css$/,` will never catch anything because  @imports are handled entirely by sass-loader/node-sass, so webpack is never involved after the first sass-rule kicks in.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following because this is what I use and I guess it gives the output you're looking for. However I'm using `scss` instead of `sass`:

```
test: /\.sass$/,
use: [
    MiniCSSExtractPlugin.loader,
    {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
            minimize: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
        }
    },          
    'sass-loader'
]

plugins: [
    new MiniCSSExtractPlugin( {
        filename: 'dist/css/[name].css' // Specify output path and file name
    })
```

Command:

```
"dev": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack --config webpack.config.js --mode=development -w",
```

Comment: If I specify any filename but, `.css` in imports , it transpiles correctly, see `.a.fff` in my example.  The issue is, I'm importing css from 3rd party library, it doesn't have `.scss` files. I don't see how your code differs from mine.

Comment: Maybe you can import the files before the `body` and just expand the classes inside the body.

Comment: Good idea, but I don't know which classes are listed in 3rd-party lib (I mean it could be `.red`, it could be `.cyan`), is there any way around unknown classes?

Comment: The 3rd party lib is it something that you include by a direct url or is it a file you downloaded. If you already downloaded the lib you can simply rename it to `_b.scss` so it is a partial. Then it should work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24307455/import-css-scss-file-into-a-class

Comment: Do you mean to copy files from `node_modules` into source directories? I would like to avoid it.

Comment: I understand that you want to avoid that but it was an option depending on the type of 3rd part library