# How can I prevent child component styles from affecting the parent component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

Is there a way to specify css that can achieve the following?

- The css of the parent component does not affect the child component
- Child component css does not affect the parent component

The child component is the one obtained by API of the external website. At this time, this child component will affect the style of the parent component (I cannot edit the style of the child component).

The main style is read by layout.
It is a style that has a large influence range, and it is troublesome to have each component read by `scoped`, so I want to avoid it.

Comment: if you are not using `scoped` then perhaps you should go for classes instead, and make sure you'll not use the class eslewhere or specifically in the parent, it doesn't really make sense to have another way around it, also if you are not writing your css class based then scoped is mandatory in order to avoid conflicts between styles in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure if this will work. But you should try using sass. And import the css with a plain css and then use the imported file inside sass. Just like this

```
<script>
   @import 'http://123.com/style.css'
</script>

<script lang=“sass”>
   #app {
      @include style
   }
</script>
```

If this doesn’t work try with one of these [Solutions - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24307455/import-css-scss-file-into-a-class)
But I know this is your go to.