# Vue : is it possible to import a js scoped only for that component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to use table component of `vue-ant` framework. I only want to import the table style. But when trying to import the `import 'ant-design-vue/lib/table/style/css'` table style all of my elements from other components are affected. Is it possible to use that styling specifically for that component only.

I tried importing it to the `<style>` tag but I encounter some errors because the `less` files expect some parameters from the javascript file

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24307455/import-css-scss-file-into-a-class) can help

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and solved it by using `style` attribute instead of `@import`. I will use your import path to demonstrate how to do it:

```html
<style scoped src="ant-design-vue/lib/table/style/css"></style>
```

Comment: i don't know why stackoverflow hide my code. anyways here is the code <style scoped src="ant-design-vue/lib/table/style/css">
</style>

Answer (score 0):

You can create scoped styles for your Vue components using the `scoped` attribute. Then import the style you need into the scoped style.

```
<style scoped>
  @import "whatever/you/want/to/import";
</style>
```

Comment: not working since the initial file to be called is js. In which thej s pass the parameter to the less files.

Comment: You can use any kind of import to add your vue-ant styles, for example inside a style tag directly. It doesn't have to be a JS import.

Comment: yah i just checked the js file and it only calls other css files.