# NG Bootstrap encapsulation issue

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am using ng-boostrap (v7.0.0) together with Angular (v10) and I am having some problems to encapsulate Bootstrap to be used in a component where a use an accordion from ng-bootstrap.

Basically the css works only if I put `@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap"` in the global file `styles.scss`. However, I want to import it only in the component `mycomponent.scss` file as this application will be published consist of a webpage that is currently using bootstrap 3 and if I import it globally instead of importing it locally, it messes up the complete webpage.

Is there a way to import ng-bootstrap using `Viewencapsulation` from angular or any other option?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a workaround:

- add a class to you component
- in the global scope create an entry for that class
- @import the bootstrap inside that selector

```
.mycomponent {  
    @import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap"; // would be better to specify which style to import instead of whole the bootstrap
}
```

You can find some more approaches in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24307455/import-css-scss-file-into-a-class).