# Is there a way to scope the third party css inside sass?

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

**Example:**

**style.scss**

```
.my-app-container {
   @import '~antd/dist/antd.css';  
}
```

Any simple integration solution on this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import css/scss file into a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24307455/import-css-scss-file-into-a-class)

Comment: it did not work